# Music disappears from playlists (yet remains in local library) upon signing up for Apple Music trial

Tags: itunes, icloud, music

When I signed up for Apple Music's free trial, all my locally ripped music disappeared from my (carefully curated) playlists yet remains in my local library with the status "**Removed from iCloud**".  Only "purchased" music remains in the playlists.

Clicking on one of the non-purchased song's status brings up three options:

- Add to iCloud music library
- Keep song
- Delete song

It seems as if the automatic process was **supposed to** automatically add all my local music to the iCloud music library, but failed.

This is my main music library on my laptop computer; the only thing I did was sign up for the free trial.

Is there a fix for this? Will unsubscribing from Apple Music fix this?

I have the default "iCloud Music Library" checked in my preferences.

Comment: They're checking iCloud Music Library by default now?  <shudder>  I'd restore your library file from your most recent backup and not EVER allow that to be turned on.  You're giving Apple permission to modify your library when you do that, and their matching algorithm is... bad.

Comment: @MarcWilson As I understand it, this checkbox uploads my non-purchased items to the cloud so they're accessible to other devices. The locally stored files (from CDs) are available in the library, they're just disappeared from the playlists. I presume because they're not yet in the cloud.  I'd like some definitive info on what's really going on!

Comment: It uploads items that Apple doesn't have in their library (or that Apple thinks they don't have in their library).  It also replaces items in your library with items Apple thinks are the same track (like iTunes Match) does.  I'd still like to know how Apple is getting around the distribution provisions of copyright by allowing the user to upload tracks.

Comment: @MarcWilson It only “replaces” them in the cloud (and secondary devices which downloaded from the cloud), right? Not your hard drive?